# DHT 11 sampling period

Tags: arduino

In the documentation of the DHT11 is said that it has sampling period of minimum 1 second. When I was using one DHT11 I could read new values exactly every 1 second or even less but on another DHT11 when the sampling period is 1 second I'm getting nan every to two measurements. The problem is gone when the sampling period is at least 1,2 seconds. Why is that different on different sensor or may the sensor be defected?

Comment: In the data sheet, it says "The only real downside of this sensor is you can only get new data from it once every 2 seconds".  Further down is says "No more than 1 Hz sampling rate (once every second".  I think what you're seeing is just part-to-part variation.

Comment: How are you doing the 1 second delay? Are you running on the internal RC oscillator of the AVR or with a more precise clock source?

Comment: I am using just Arduino's delay function

Comment: I will say something that will not answer your question: if an application is so critical that it can't wait 2 or 3 seconds between readings from the sensor, it should not use a generic sensor like DHT11, or even it should not use a code with "delays", probably the firmware should be using some kind of real-time code.